# Highlighting specified text with embedded link with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Here is my `content.js` which has a function that highlights specified text.

```
function isElementVisible(element) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    return style.display !== 'none' && style.visibility !== 'hidden';
  }

  function highlightLetter(node, targetLetter, highlightColor, tooltipContent) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && isElementVisible(node.parentElement)) {
      const textContent = node.textContent;
  
      // Match targetLetter only if it is the first or last character of a word
      const pattern = new RegExp(`\\b${targetLetter}|${targetLetter}\\b`, 'gi');
  
      const newContent = textContent.replace(pattern, match => `<span class="tooltip"><mark style="background-color: ${highlightColor}">${match}</mark><span class="tooltiptext">${tooltipContent}</span></span>`);
  
      if (newContent !== textContent) {
        const newNode = document.createElement('span');
        newNode.innerHTML = newContent;
        node.replaceWith(newNode);
      }
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && isElementVisible(node)) {
      node.childNodes.forEach(childNode => highlightLetter(childNode, targetLetter, highlightColor, tooltipContent));
    }
  }
```

Here are the other files for a minimal reproducible example.
Here is my `manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Text Highlighter",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Highlight text in a web page.",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["styles.css"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is my `styles.css`

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Hide the tooltip by default */
  .tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
  }

  /* Display the tooltip when hovering over the parent span */
  .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

I tried to highlight this part of the html, as you can see it has a link embedded within the text. (link to actual page: https://www.cnn.com/2023/12/31/politics/donald-trump-2024-voter-turnout/index.html):
`The former president leads the current president in more than his fair share of polls of registered voters, including in a number of <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/2023/11/05/us/politics/biden-trump-2024-poll.html" target="_blank">key swing states</a>`

I called the function in `content.js`
`highlightLetter(document.body, 'The former president leads the current president in more than his fair share of polls of registered voters, including in a number of key swing states.', 'red', '[insert tooltip content]');`

but it did not highlight anything, I'm thinking its because it extended across multiple nodes because of the embedded link. How can I make this work?

Comment: Your text spans 3 nodes: 2 text nodes and one link. You can only target one node with your function. Also, check the element's visibility after checking the text because getComputedStyle is super slow. A better solution is to use `mark.js` library.